QGIS - Reference a widget added via Drag and Drop designer using a Python action
Background
I have used the Drag and Drop designer to add a Text Widget to my attributes form. The title was left as the default Text Widget and the placeholder text some text was added.
I created a simple Python action called Trigger Action and also added it to my form with the Drag and Drop designer (this generates a button in the form).
My attributes form looks like this.

Where 1. and 2. are the Text Widget and the Python Action respectively.
The goal
The goal is to update the text in Text widget to something arbritary when I trigger the Python action by referencing the widget using PyQGIS in the Python Action.
Current method
In the Python Action editor, using the supplied convenience variable form the attribute form's child widgets can be listed.
print(form.children())

<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGridLayout object at 0x000002C9F2970430>  
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel object at 0x000002C9C70073A0>   
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget object at 0x000002C9C7007430>   
...


After some digging around in the form's hierarchy, I came to realise that form.children()[2] (a QWidget) is the parent of widgets added via the Drag and Drop designer.
I can identify my Text Widget by doing:
parent_widget = form.children()[2]
widgets = parent_widget.children()

for w in widgets:
    print(w)
    if hasattr(w, 'text'):
        print(w.text())

<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGridLayout object at 0x000002C9F2970430>  
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel object at 0x000002C9C70073A0>  
fid  
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget object at 0x000002C9C7007430>  
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel object at 0x000002C9C70074C0>  
Text Widget  
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel object at 0x000002C9C7007550>  
some text

So, now I know that my target Text Widget (a QLabel) is form.children()[2].children()[4].
The problem
This seems like a convoluted way of finding the widget, and it relies on there being placeholder text already present.
Question
Is there a more robust way of referencing a widget added using the Drag and Drop designer?
I had hoped that the Title option set when configuring the widget would somehow end up in the widget's properties (its objectName for example), but, after searching for it, I cannot find it. I may have missed it.

